# Replacing broken CSR8670CG on BOSE soundlink color 2

Tags: bootloader, firmware

Injecting 4V DC directly on the PCB as shown in the following image

[image: Injection point]

I got the CSR8670CG IC becoming very hot.

[image: IC CSR8670CG]

I suspect that the IC is broken and I am wondering if changing it is a feasible option.
I know that it should be programmed with BOSE's firmware and I read that it could be updated with their [updater](https://btu.bose.com) when the it gets stuck, especially after battery problems. It seems strange to me. Isn't it necessary to have a working bootloader to load the firmware via USB? Do new chips come with such capability? I wasn't able to find this information on the IC's datasheet.

Maybe it should be programmed soldering a connector on the pads labeled J202 on the back of the board?

[image: J202]

Edit1: I’ve figured out the jumper J202 mapping.

Pin1 -> G3

Pin2 -> E1

Pin3 -> M1

Pin4 -> B2

Pin5 -> G11

Pin6 -> L2

Clearly it is meant for programming the chip.

Comment: This will be a complicating factor for you, from the datasheet: "embedded flash memory".

Comment: Best case scenario, something is shorted downstream of CSR8670CG, causing it to heat up.

Comment: @winny I've used a thermal camera and only the IC was hot.

Comment: Yes, most likely the CSR8670CG itself is at fault, but it is plausible that there is a hard short to ground on any of its outputs, which would cause the CSR8670CG to heat up, not the hard short. Look up the datasheet, try to trace out all outputs from it and measure the resistance to ground.

Comment: I think that the only solution is to get a chip from a spare board, because even programming the chip using SPI requires a firmware which is not public.

Comment: That's probably a good option. If you are lucky, it's just a bootloader which won't put up a fight.

Comment: Wait a minute! Maybe I’ve found something useful here https://github.com/bosefirmware/ced

Comment: Great! Check for shorts first, or you will be transplanting the chip in vain.

Comment: I’ve removed the chip and now there are no more shorts on the board. Time to reverse engineer the J202 header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150081/discussion-between-winny-and-stenio).

Comment: @stenio Were you able to restore the device? A similar situation, the CSR8670CG microcircuit heats up very strongly???

Comment: @Oleh Unfortunately I ripped off some pads removing the chip. Maybe I'll try to repair them in the future, but it seems a very difficult task.